# How to avoid series of commands running under sql plus using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus

I have created a script which runs a series of other instances in shell using the while command. But the problem is that one of the job is connecting to sql plus and running the remaining command under sqlplus.

For ex. my input file --> job.txt

```
job1
job2
job3
```

Now, using the below script I am calling job one by one. So, until the present job is finished next job wont start. But the catch comes when the job tries to connect the sql plus. After it connects to sql plus, the process id of the current job gets complete and remaining jobs run as the sql statement in unix env.

```
while read line;
do 
    $job1 
done < job.txt;
```

Error message I am getting in sqlplus after current instance exits.

```
SP2-0042: unknown command
```

How can I avoid bringing the jobs under sqlplus.

Comment: No one interested ???

Comment: **1** no need for `;` chars in your while loop, it is not written all on one line.  **2** the `$a` between `do` and `done` should be `$line`.  **3** please provide a realistic example, as presented it is too vague to help.  **4** if a, b and c are commands, each of these must complete properly on their own before you can call them.